# Как мне задать анимацию с момента загрузки страницы?

Tags: jquery

Чтобы эффект слайдера был как на этом сайте http://goodsklad24.ru/
То есть при загрузке 1 слайд всегда выезжает сверху.
Весь слайдер который я имею вот:

```
` https://codepen.io/poylar/pen/vvrxVa`
```

Comment: где Ваша html разметка?

Comment: https://codepen.io/poylar/pen/vvrxVa

Comment: код желательно включать в вопрос

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема в том, что  первый слайд при загрузке уже стоит в конечной точке анимации.  Нужно чтобы изначально слайд был "выше", и с `opacity : 0`

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
     // импровизированный стиль при загрузке страницы, чтобы последующая анимация имела точку начала и конец. 
      $('.first-slide').css({marginTop: "-10rem", opacity: "0"});
      // здесь забыли точку в  $('.first-slide') и время проигрывания анимации
      $('.first-slide').animate({ marginTop: "0rem", paddingBottom: "0", opacity: "1" }, 1000);
      $('.second-slide').css({ marginTop: "-20rem", paddingBottom: "20rem", opacity: "0" });
      $('.third-slide').css({ marginTop: "-20rem", paddingBottom: "20rem", opacity: "0" });


    })
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, все получилось